# Numpy array equality boolean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

The following two approaches should yield an identical result, but it seems they do not:

**Approach 1**:

```
#Generate an array with 12 annual fractions corresponding to each month
ann_frac = np.arange(1,13,1).reshape([12,1])
ann_frac = ann_frac[:,0]/12
```

Output:

```
array([0.08333333, 0.16666667, 0.25      , 0.33333333, 0.41666667,
       0.5       , 0.58333333, 0.66666667, 0.75      , 0.83333333,
       0.91666667, 1.        ])
```

**Approach 2**:

```
i = np.arange(1,13,1)
ann_frac2 = (i/12).reshape([12,1])
```

Output:

```
array([[0.08333333],
       [0.16666667],
       [0.25      ],
       [0.33333333],
       [0.41666667],
       [0.5       ],
       [0.58333333],
       [0.66666667],
       [0.75      ],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.91666667],
       [1.        ]])
```

**Comparing approaches**:

```
ann_frac2==ann_frac
```

Output:

```
array([[False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]])
```

A bit strange it seems. Any explanation? Obviously, if one just wants to compare numbers in two different arrays for equlity, the example above demonstrates that even though the numbers can be identical, the way the numbers were created and stored can produce an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: You should compare equally shaped arrays `ann_frac2.ravel()==(ann_frac[:,0]/12)`

Comment: `ann_frac[:,0]/12` doesn't modify ann_frac

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. I have adjusted the code as: ann_frac = (1/12)*np.arange(1,13,1).reshape([12,1]). Then I get: 

array([[ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [ True],
       [ True]])

Must be a rounding thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing arrays with different dimensionality. What I guess you want is

```
ann_frac = np.arange(1,13,1).reshape([12,1])
ann_frac1 = ann_frac[:,0]/12
i = np.arange(1,13,1)
ann_frac2 = (i/12).reshape([12,1])
ann_frac3 = (i/12).reshape(12)
```

and the correct comparison should be

```
ann_frac3==ann_frac1
```

with output

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
    True,  True,  True])
```

Even better would be

```
(ann_frac3==ann_frac1).all()
```

with output

```
True
```